# JSON help to colour code sharepoint list header

Tags: json, sharepoint, splist

I would like to be able to colourcode the header cells in a sharepoint list on O365. The standard format provided is
{
"$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json"
}

Can anyone help provide the JSON code to add a colour to the header cell in Orange and make the text white?

I tried using the code from changing the column properties, but keep getting an error in the code build. It may be I wasn't using the correct term for the column header. I don't want to colour the column itself, just the header.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, we can't customize SharePoint List headers using JSON formatting. We can only control what's displayed inside a table cell. This is a known limitation of JSON formatting in SharePoint.

I found a thread similar to yours, please check it out: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/303892/sharepoint-modern-list-change-fill-color-of-column-headers

Comment: Thank you for your answer, which whilst it didn't provide a solution, it did at least confirm the position that this is not achievable without losing OOTB functionality.